# How to change my hostname in network connection

Tags: configuration, hostname, hosts, etc

i want to change my hostname that appears in my router DHCP
things that i already tried

```
sudo hostname ___
```

also tried to change it from `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts`

Answer (score 0):

you need to do that on the router not on the host.

this will typically be done by assigning an ip and hostname combination to the mac address of the network adapter you use on your host.

Comment: My router uses the device's hostname, but I found that it caches it, so it doesn't refresh if I change it.

Comment: if you host is set with a specific hostname it will include this in the DHCP query , this will be how the router knows about it. It will be cached for the lifetime of the DHCP lease.